# How to remove depcecated error's from PHP file

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have developed an application in php. I have upgraded my version now i am getting Deprecated warning. I know i need to used latest code but right now i need to hide this warning. I have also added error_reporting(E_ALL); at the start of my php file but still i am getting deprecated warning. Any Help

Comment: Er... `E_ALL` means "all errors". That's the opposite of what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would only hide well-known deprecation messages you're aware of but don't have time to fix right now. You can easily do so with a [custom error handler](http://php.net/set_error_handler). For instance, this one hides all error messages that start with `mysql_`:

```
set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr){
    return strpos($errstr, 'mysql_') === 0;
}, E_DEPRECATED);
```

Things to consider:

- `$errstr` is the text of the error message
- Return `true` to omit the error, `false` to process it

Tweak to your exact needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);` instead. This will show all errors except deprecations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Gergo i have placed this line in the start of my php file but still i am getting deprecated message warning.